# Internet Explorer commandline arguments

Tags: command-line, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to run Internet Explorer from a batch file/scheduled task.

My batch file contains (in its entirety):

```
cd "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explore"
iexplore.exe http://superuser.com -nohome
```

When I run the batch file the URL picks up the command line argument, rather than acting on it.

> http://superuser.com%20-nohome/

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but don't see what at the moment. What is the solution?

This is on Windows 7 Home Premium, with Internet Explorer 8.

**UPDATE in response to comments:**

I got the `nohome` from some site or other, possibly the one mentioned in the comments. The previous attempt was actually using `nohangrecovery` which is documented *[Internet Explorer Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-ieak/ie-setup-command-line-options-and-return-codes)*.

My original attempt looked like this (which is actually as per the MSDN documentation:

```
cd "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explore"
iexplore.exe -nohangrecovery http://superuser.com
```

This results in the address bar containing:

> http://-nohangrecovery%20http//superuser.com

Sorry if this is a duplicate - I couldn't see any matches when I searched.

Comment: Is it possible that \Internet Explore is a typo? Isn't it Internet Explorer?

Comment: That's a good point - well spotted. Its workng anyway, probably cos the bat file is in the Internet Explorer folder and I'm just clicking on it at the moment.

Comment: It might be because iexplore.exe is in the PATH which means that even if you're 'cd' ing to another directory, Windows is still finding the exe in the PATH.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx No longer valid.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Taa updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please refer to [the documentation for Internet Explorer command-line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025.aspx). Command-line options should go before the URL, and `-nohome` is not even a supported option. Where did you learn about `-nohome`?

Comment: Nohome is mentioned on this page referencing command line arguments. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=73898 It seems very outdated and this switch is possibly no longer supported as it is not referenced in newer material

Comment: It's all right with William's solution! Since "iexplore" is a "known command" for Windows, you can start it everywhere using use "start iexplore -nohome http://www.bol.com.br/" (1 command line) instead of entering Internet Explorer folder and then executing that (2 command lines).

Comment: Fair comment about nohome. I had already tried other args and ordering. What I pasted into the question was based on other searches on google. See my update for more.

Comment: Curses - just noticed that the option I'm trying to use is IE9, not IE8. Guess that makes your re-pointer to the docu the answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just use this command:

> "%ProgramFiles%\Internet
>   Explorer\iexplorer.exe"
>   http://superuser.com

No need for the cd\

Comment: Original: "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexploreR.exe" http://superuser.com (with extra "r" near the end of "iexplorer.exe" capitalized to show difference)

Fixed: Remove the "r" typo and you get:  "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://superuser.com

Which can be copied and pasted and will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to open up Super User every time you log in via a batch file then simply put in:

> cd "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explore"
>   iexplore.exe http://superuser.com

However, if you're doing this to log in for 100 days consecutively then this won't work. I won't tell you why, but it won't :-)

Comment: lol - no I'm not. I'm mostly on StackOVerflow and I just lost a run of 29 consec days there by not paying attention on Sunday!!! The URL in the example is subbed in for the real one that I'm using.

Comment: Ah ok, I lost a 94 day run by having a hungover Sunday, was gutted. If you just remove the -nohome parameter it should work fine. I've tested it here and its working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cd` and going to the directory you could just do:

```
start "" iexplore http://superuser.com
```

or just:

```
start iexplore http://superuser.com
```

`-nohome` should be put before the url. I'm not sure if the command exists.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `-noframemerging` switch at the end of the Internet Explorer shortcut and you will have separate sessions. This works in Windows 10 using Internet Explorer 11.